# Get tagname name value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, selector, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get the tagname of name from the below line of code. I have to get the name from the below tagname using javascript

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

i need to get **webviewbounce**

This is what i know.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("preference")
```

But it doesnt give me the **preference name**. What i want is the tagname of name which is `webviewbounce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector` to get the element. It will return the first matched element.Then use `getAttribute` to get the required attribute from the element.
If there are multiple tag element with same tagname , use `document.querySlectorAll`

```js
var getElem = document.querySelector('preference'),
  getNameProperty = getElem.getAttribute('name');
console.log(getNameProperty)
```

```html
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByName("webviewbounce");
```

This will get the element that has the name of `webviewbounce`

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` is going to return a collection of elements. You can then use `getAttribute()` to get the name property of the first item in the collection.

```
console.log( document.getElementsByTagName( "preference" )[0].getAttribute( 'name' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const p = document.getElementsByTagName('preference')

console.log(p[0])
// <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false">…</preference>

console.log(p[0].getAttribute('name'))
// webviewbounce
```

```html
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering this as your first element of preference tag. this would give document.getElementsByTagName("preference")["0"].name the name. The "0" in the line code should be changed to the exact element.

In addition you can also use getAttribute('name') with getElementsByTagName().

Answer (score 0):

You can use getAttribute to get the name value of the tag.

You can try something like this.

```
var element = document.getElementByTagName("preference");
var name = element.getAttribute("name");
console.log(name);
```