# TagName value from variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How i can get tagName value using javascript?

```
var htmlString="<html><body><img src="1"/><img src="2"/></body></html>";
var imagesNodes=htmlString.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

This is what i have tried so far but i gives error.

Comment: you need `src` right ?, because `img` tag does not have `value` attribute

Comment: Which error is it giving you ?

Comment: Your first line can't compile, you need to escape the double quotes inside the string .

Comment: What does your question mean exactly ? What is your expected output in this example ?

Comment: [Check this link hope it will help you solve your problem, happy coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015552/get-tagname-name-value-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get an `HtmlCollection` of your `<img>`, you need to parse your string first to a `Node` using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), and then you can use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
let htmlParser = new DOMParser();
//remember to escape your quotes
let htmlString = "<html><body><img src=\"1\"/><img src=\"2\"/></body></html>"; 

let htmlDoc = htmlParser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html"); //Node
let imgCollection = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("img"); //both of your <img>
```

Answer (score 0):

htmlString is a string, not a document object. 
"getElementsByTagName" is available only for document object and you can't use it in a string, unless you do `innerHTML` the hidden div class and try to get element by Tag there.